# How to pack dependencies for a forge mod while also avoiding class conflicts?

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft, minecraft-forge

This is currently my build.gradle file (I removed unnecessary task references, which are not only working perfectly fine, but are irrelevant to the current question):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            name = 'forge'
            url = 'https://files.minecraftforge.net/maven'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:2.1-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle.forge'
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile('some.library:here:1.2.3') // no extra modules
    compile('other.library:here:4.5.6') // multiple modules
}

jar {
    from project.configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
}
```

Currently I have a system which will automatically pack all the dependencies into my jar file. The main issue I have is that if another mod or file loads the same library before my mod, I will end up with a class loading problem, because I'll be loading the same class twice (one from another jar, and one from my own).

With that being said, is it possible to avoid such an issue? How would I realistically account for such a thing? Does forge perhaps have a method to control class loading to the extent that duplicate libraries will not be loaded, hence there will be no class conflicts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minecraft Forge supports a feature called shading to deal with this problem. When you shade a jar, it's integrated into your jar, but the package is renamed to something unique (along with all references to it from your code).

Source: https://github.com/MinecraftForge/ForgeGradle/blob/FG_1.2/docs/user-guide/shading.md

Comment: Is there a new link for this guide? that one seems to 404

Comment: @JaakKütt Try it now.

Comment: The linked guide has a last commit 2015 and does not seem to work anymore, in particular the srgExtra bit. Is there an updated version?

Comment: @Tim Morris change minecraft { srgExtra } to reobf { jar { extraLine { } } } https://forums.minecraftforge.net/topic/36791-trying-to-shade-dependencies-into-jar/?do=findComment&comment=250922